# Getting the text from a JMenuItem that is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

Currently using SWING to implement a JMenuBar, where there are 2 different JMenus. One is called gameMenu, and one is called, addMenuGame.

I have several JMenuItems in gameMenu, which are all implemented with this method, in my interface controller.

```
public void addGameMenu(JMenu control) {
    String fileName = "gamemodes.txt";
    try {

        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);

        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

        String line;

        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

            String split[] = line.split("#");
            for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                control.add(split[i]);
            }

        }

        bufferReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Fejl ved linje:" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

what it does, is read every line from a text file, and adds that to the JMenu, called gameMenu. However, I can only add actionlisteners to the JMenu, and not the JMenuItem, that is of JMenu. In the JFrame main void, this is how I implement it:

```
public class index extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    QuizzControlHandler dd = new QuizzControlHandler();
    private JMenuItem dc;

    /**
     * Creates new form index
     */
    public index(){

        initComponents();
        dd.addGameMenu(menuGame); 

    }

}
```

This will fill my menu correctly, however, I need to retrieve what the user is clicking on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I can only add actionlisteners to the JMenu, and not the JMenuItem,

The user clicks on the `JMenuItem` so you need to add the `ActionListener` to the `JMenuItem` NOT the JMenu.

Before you invoke the `addGameMenu(...)` you can create an `ActionListener` to be shared by all the JMenuItems with code like:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
        System.out.println(menuItem.getText());
    }
}
```

Then you would change your `addGameMenu(JMenu control, ActionListener al)` to have a second parameter.

Then in the method you change:

```
//control.add(split[i]);
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem( split[I] );
menuItem.addActionListener( al );
control.add( menuItem );
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough brother, on point with that explanation... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Camickr beat me to it.

You're adding simple Strings to your JMenu when you should be adding constructed JMenuItems. In other words, don't add dumb objects to the menu when you can add smart ones. For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestMenus extends JPanel {
    public TestMenus() {

    }

    public void addGameMenu(JMenu control) {

        String[] texts = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
            control.add(new JMenuItem(new MenuItemAction(texts[i])));
        }
    }

    private class MenuItemAction extends AbstractAction {
        public MenuItemAction(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Menu item: " + e.getActionCommand());
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TestMenus mainPanel = new TestMenus();

        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        mainPanel.addGameMenu(menu);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(menu);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestMenus");
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Appreciate it brother, goofy mistake from my side, just thought there was an easier way to get J Items from a JMenu, suppose it wasn't that simple. Thanks alot brother!